# How to use Vite to compile several separate assets: Javascript apps, Sass files etc

Tags: javascript, sass, vite

I have a project that has several parts within it, e.g. my input are:

- `src/somethingCool.js` (A Svelte app, which sucks in a lot of src/*svelte files)
  → `public/somethingCool.js` (bundled .js file)
- `src/site.scss` (Sass that may import a bunch more .scss files)
  → `public/site.css`
- `src/editor.scss` (Sass, separate from the above)
  → `public/editor.css`
- `src/somethingVanilla.js` (Vanilla js that wants minifying)
  → `public/somethingVanilla.js`

How would I configure Vite to achieve this? I'd like it to 'watch' the files, too and recompile them any time they change. I don't need Vite's dev server running; I just want the output files; I'm compiling these assets for use in a separate project. Sourcemaps would be a bonus.

I've tried a few things, but I always end up with one file of CSS, one of .js.

Until recently I've used laravel-mix to achieve this; it's API is perfect, e.g.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('src/somethingCool.js', 'dist').svelte()
   .sass('src/site.scss', 'public/')
   .sass('src/editor.scss', 'public/')
   .js('src/somethingVanilla.js', 'dist')
;
```